# ST_Buffer in meters from 4326 point table

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, buffer

I would like to create 100 meters circle buffers in a UTM projection from a point table whose SRID is EPSG:4326 and keeping the id column.
I wonder what is the straightest way. Is that possible to get it in one query after having created a buffer table with the URM SRID? Like:

```
INSERT INTO buffers SELECT id_points, ST_Buffer (geom, 100 , 'quad_segs=8') AS geom from points
```

but this would require I guess to add ST_transform somewhere and ST_Buffer does not like to involve two different SRID.

Comment: Just cast to `geography` within the buffer request.

Comment: it seems it required to be cast twice: `INSERT INTO buffers SELECT id_points, CAST(ST_Buffer(CAST(points.geom AS geography), 100 , 'quad_segs=8') AS geometry) AS geom from points`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: or `points.geom::geography`,...`)::geometry`